# Multiple labels inside tooltip of the pin marker with click events in Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using XamarinForms.GoogleMaps. Is it possible to show multiple labels stacked inside the tooltip of the Pin? I want to perform certain actions by clicking each label.
I saw that I can only pass the label text to the Label property

```
  Pins.Add(new Pin
                    {
                        Type = PinType.Place,
                        Address = ””,
                        Label = “label text goes here”,
                        Position = new Position(Convert.ToDouble(obj.GeoLat),
                            Convert.ToDouble(obj.GeoLng))
                    });
```

Require output should be like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Add new property in `CustomPin` class .

```
public string[] Details { get; set; }
```

2. Assign the value .

```
CustomPin pin = new CustomPin
{
    Type = PinType.Place,
    Position = new Position(37.79752, -122.40183),
    Label = "Test",
    Address = "394 Pacific Ave, San Francisco CA",
    Name = "Xamarin",
    Url = "http://xamarin.com/about/",

    Details = new string[] {"111","222","333"}  //this line
};
```

3. Build the interface in Custom renderer .

```
 void OnDidSelectAnnotationView(object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e)
        {
            CustomMKAnnotationView customView = e.View as CustomMKAnnotationView;
            CustomPin pin = GetCustomPin(customView.Annotation as MKPointAnnotation);

            customPinView = new UIView();
            customPinView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
            if (customView.Name.Equals("Xamarin"))
            {

                int index = 0;
                foreach(var item in pin.Details)
                {
                    UILabel label = new UILabel(new CGRect(0, index * 30, 100, 20));
                    label.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
                    label.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
                    label.Text = item;
                    customPinView.Add(label);
                    index++;
                }
                customPinView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 100, index*30);
                customPinView.Center = new CGPoint(0, -(e.View.Frame.Height + 75));
                e.View.AddSubview(customPinView);
            }
        }
```

[image]

##### Update

If you're using  `XamarinForm.GoogleMaps` , `Pin` class is sealed class so we can't create sub class , but we can set value with `Tag`  property ,refer to [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f1ae9f0e-a7d2-4cea-af21-ec580107519a/how-i-can-create-a-custom-pin-in-googlemaps?forum=xamarinandroid) .

```
//xaml

pin.Tag = new string[] {"111","222","333"};
```

```
//custom renderer
 string[] details = pin.Tag as string[];
 foreach(var item in details)
 {
      UILabel label = new UILabel(new CGRect(0, index * 30, 100, 20));
      label.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
      label.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
      label.Text = item;
      customPinView.Add(label);
      index++;
 }
```

Comment: I am using XamarinForm.GoogleMaps, and in that I can not inherit the Pin class to add custom attributes to it.

Comment: Please check my update .